# Unknown custom element <v-expansion-panels>?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using the latest version of Vuetify, `npm info vuetify` : vuetify@2.0.15

Certain elements (for example `v-timeline`) are able to display well, but I am unable to use `v-expansion-panels` even with the latest version:

```html
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-expansion-panels>
      <v-expansion-panel v-for="(item,i) in 5" :key="i">
        <v-expansion-panel-header>Item</v-expansion-panel-header>
        <v-expansion-panel-content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</v-expansion-panel-content>
      </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-expansion-panels>
  <v-container>
<template>
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: If you are using the a-la-carte method described in the documentation then it should automatically register all the components used in your project.

Comment: `npm info vuetify` just tells you about the version *available in NPM*, not what you have installed in your `node_modules`. Instead, use `npm ls vuetify` in your project directory (or manually inspect the `package.json` of the installed package).

Comment: Can you edit this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-wxv2k?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FExpanderDemo.vue)
 to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @tony19 you're right, the version I have in my current project is version 1.5, but the latest version is version 2

Comment: make sure you're referring to the correct docs. default is 2.x whereas you probably have 1.5.x

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a version mismatch, using Vuetify 1.5.x with `v-extension-panels` 2.x (like in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetifys-v-expansion-panel-demo-gqj74?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14)), which would result in an error similar to this:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-expansion-panels> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

The solution is to either downgrade the component to [1.5.x](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels), or upgrade Vuetify to [2.0.x](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels). The following `VExpansionPanel`-specific details might help you convert the code.

*Pseudo-element hierarchy (common):*

```
 + parent container
 |___+ item container 1
 |   |___ item header
 |   |___ item content
 |
 |---+ item container 2
 |   |___ item header
 |   |___ item content
 ⋮
 |___+ item container N
     |___ item header
     |___ item content
```

*`VExpansionPanel` differences:*

```
                 ‖             1.5.x                  |          2.0.x
=======================================================================================
parent container ‖  <v-expansion-panel>               | <v-expansion-panels> (plural)
item container   ‖  <v-expansion-panel-content>       | <v-expansion-panel>
item header      ‖  <template v-slot:header>          | <v-expansion-panel-header>
item content     ‖  *default slot of item container*  | <v-expansion-panel-content>
```

*Template examples:*

```html
<!-- 1.5.x -->
<template>
  <v-expansion-panel>
    <v-expansion-panel-content
      v-for="(item,i) in 5"
      :key="i"
    >
      <template v-slot:header>
        <div>Item</div>
      </template>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>
          Lorem ipsum ...
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</template>
```

[1.5.x demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetifys-v-expansion-panel-demo-v15x-o7b2k?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FExpanderDemo.vue)

```html
<!-- 2.0.x -->
<template>
  <v-expansion-panels>
    <v-expansion-panel
      v-for="(item,i) in 5"
      :key="i"
    >
      <v-expansion-panel-header>
        Item
      </v-expansion-panel-header>
      <v-expansion-panel-content>
        Lorem ipsum ...
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-expansion-panels>
</template>
```

[2.0.x demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-wxv2k?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FExpanderDemo.vue)